# Alternate function variable outside it

Tags: javascript

I am trying to **sort an array** just to train but I am having trouble for it.
It's hard for me to understand how functions really works, even by using google or documentation i can't find my answer. 
I am having trouble to know **if I can use my variable `j` to interact with my function** to avoid to count from the beginning in my loop for.
Can I do it? 
And of course if you have **an other way to selection sort**, I am sure there is an other please let give me your answer if you have time. 
Here is what I tried:

```
var array = [8, 4, 2, 9, 4, 3, 7, 1, 6, 40, 21, 30];


function findMini(j) {
    var min = 100;  
    var count = j;

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (i = 0) {
            min = array[i + count];
            i = i + j;
        }
        else if (array[i] < min) {
            min = array[i];
        }
        else {

        }
    }
    return min;
}


for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    console.log('Le tableau [ ' + j + ' ] = ' + findMini(j));
}
```

and last question, can I declare a variable like this `var min = 100;` with `undefined` value?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear...

Comment: If i understood you want to sort an array using selection sort? is yes follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898928/selection-sort-in-javascript

Comment: For your last question - can I declare a variable like this var min = 100; with undefined value? The answer is yes you can - var min=undefined;

Comment: It would probably be better to set `min` to `Infinity` or to `array[0]`

Comment: first i would understand why it doesn't work and second yeah i was searching for an other solution. sorry to be unclear, i thought i was :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first I recommend learning javascript variable scope:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

The problem in your code is that the variable array is declared outside the function. If you want to use it inside your function, you can declare it inside or using it as a parameter for the function:

```
function findMini(j, arrayInsideFunction) {
  ......
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayInsideFunction.length; i++) {
  ......
}
.......
console.log('Le tableau [ ' + j + ' ] = ' + findMini(j, array));
```

Then, regarding the second question, you can declare an undefined variable:

```
var min = undefined;
```

You can also just define the variable and use it later

```
var min;
```

Comment: thank you very much, i read the w3school doc but couldn't find it, thanks for the answer by the way and sorry to ask something wich was on internet aparently...